# asp.net repeater control for displaying images and associated names

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, repeater, image-gallery, datarepeater

I want to implement an image gallery in asp.net/C#. I am using sql server 2008, visual studio 2010 and .NET 4.0.

I have made a webpage and now want to display 6 images as thumbnails (and their names just below the thumbnails) at the center of the page. The format of the display is something like this:

```
img1     img2   img3  
`<name1`> `<name2`> `<name3`>  

img4     img5   img6  
`<name4`> `<name5`> `<name6`>  

1 2 3 4 Next>
```

Basic operation is like this:

I pull images from a database and then display them as above as thumbnails.

The `1 2 3 Next>` are links depending on whether there are more than 6 images pulled from the DB. So basically the numbering `1 2 3 4 Next>` is dynamic depending on how many images exist.

Can anyone give me a basic overview of how this an be achieved? Should I be using a asp:Repeater or a asp:DataList for this kind of a display? Please let me know if additional details required. Thanks in advance for any suggestions/guidance/help.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to see this examples

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/NickPhotoBrowser.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/thumbtools.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/NetPix.aspx

They have what you ask on source code and you can get ideas on how to do it.

Comment: thanks Aristos! These examples at least look like what I intend to achieve on my page. I will study their source code and put up any questions that I might have to them as well as here. Thanks again.